# How to dispose transient resolved object in unity

Tags: c#, unity-container

this is my constractor:

```
public class Foo
{
    private ICar car;
    public Foo()
    {
        car = CurrentUnityContainer.Container.Resolve<Car>();
    }
    public MyMethod()
    {
        car.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

I resolve Car class manually, my question is how can i dispose car object? we have memory leak problem and think that because we do not dispose this objects is our problem.

Comment: Proper DI frameworks automatically dispose registered services. I suspect you have to keep on looking for your memory leak using profilers. If you want to dispose it yourself, then you could manually call 'car.Dispose()', if it implements 'IDisposable' of course.

Comment: Is `Car` Disposable? I don't see any difference in an instance resolved that way or just newed up. You handle them the same.

Answer (score 0):

If it's transient, could you just dispose it when Foo is disposed?

```
public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    private ICar car;
    public Foo()
    {
        car = CurrentUnityContainer.Container.Resolve<Car>();
    }
    public MyMethod()
    {
        car.DoSomething();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        car.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Since every resolution should create a new instance of Car.